# If pref(L) is regular, does that imply L is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

I have this exercise for homework:

> Say we have a language `L`. we know that the language `pref(L)` (all the prefixes of `L`, including all the words in `L` itself) is a regular language. Does this imply that the language `L` is regular as well?

I took the NFA of `pref(L)` and divided it (via 2 epsilon transitions from `q0`) to 2 separate NFA's, as 1 defines `L` and the other defines `pref(L)\L`.

What I actually got is a NFA for `L`, which means it is regular.

I am not sure this is the way or if it legal. I'd be glad for another lead.

Comment: Have you performed your construction on a small example? Did it work?

Answer (score 3):

What you say doesn't make sense. How can you operate with a NFA for $L$ if you cant be sure that $L$ is regular?

Try to consider this language
$$L=\{ uu \mid u \in \Sigma^*\}$$
This language is not regular, it is not even context-free, which can be shown with the pumping lemma. I think from here you can continue by yourself. What is $\text{pref}(L)$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure pref(L) isn't regular either. All the words in L are also in pref(L) because a whole word is a prefix of itself. If there's no NFA for L, there won't be an NFA for pref(L).

Comment: Languages based on unary alphabets are also very practical, they often simplify the problem. Assume $L=\{a^{2^n} \mid n \in N\}$. Is $L$ regular? What is $pref(L)$?